# How i do Update SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I want to update my databases tables, but I get this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The variable name '@ssn' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP\BILSAY;Initial Catalog=Railway System;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employe SET SSN=@ssn,Name=@Name,Surname=@Surname,Address=@Address,Age=@Age,Phone=@Phone,Profession=@Profession WHERE SSN=@SSN ",conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profesion", textBox8.Text);

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        Employe emp = new Employe();
        emp.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated.");
   }
   catch (SqlException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occurs!");
    }
  }
}
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The variable name
>   '@ssn' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within
>   a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - you're adding two parameters with the same name ("@ssn").  Rename one of them (in the SQL and the parameter function.

Comment: Remove one or the other 
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", textBox2.Text);` also why are you not `Disposing` of the newly created form when you exit out of it..? please use the debugger to step thru your code..

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear - you're adding two parameters with the same name (`"@ssn"`).  You have some options:

- Rename one of the paraters (in the SQL and the `Parameters.AddWithValue` call
- Don't update the `SSN` colume since that's the key value you're using
- Add an independent primary key column (like an auto-increment integer) and use *that* for lookups instead of SSN.

Answer (score 0):

You have `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn"...` 2 times. The exception is normal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the parameter twice. If you're looking to change the value of the parameter after you've added it try changing the existing parameters value property with this     `cmd.Parameters("@ssn").value = "somevalue"`